# Dripping supply line from the toilet cut off valve

Tags: toilet

My toilet supply line is dripping, I can’t get it to stop. I had a dripping packing nut when the line was attached to the toilet, but since it was leaking in three places, I turned off the water and detached the supply line. As I was saying, now it’s just dripping out of the supply line into a watering can.

I have the pros coming in 10 days to replace my toilet and the shut off valve (old and likely the cause of this!anything I can do to keep me sane? I’ve tried the penetrating oil on the pack nut.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Valid feedback. I’ll see what I can do. Lol, I was able to buy a new watering can so the supply line just lips onto that and it drips right in, at least I’ll sleep through the night!

Comment: And there you go. Pretty crusty valve. Just trying to stop the drip out of the supply line. I think if I try to stop it, it will just drip from the nut

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick: purchase a new shut off valve (it looks like a 1/2 inch size supply line). Remove the supply hose and wrap Teflon tape around the threads.

Install the new valve onto the old one. You should get a new supply hose (1/2 inch x 7/8 inch). Connect it to the new valve and the toilet valve.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I knew that, and am having a new toilet put in. I have a washlet and when I installed it, the truth came out. Time for an upgrade and today it’s marginally more expensive to just buy a new toilet.

Comment: Jeremy, please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and if you don't intend to resolve this post please delete it.